# JS deep compare 2 objects and remove items found in the second but not the first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 'filter object' such as :

```
var  filterObj =  { name: '',
      age: '',
      address: {street: '', city: ''},
      friends: [name: '']
    }
```

and then an object such as:

```
 var obj =   { name: 'Bob',
      age: '23',
      car: 'Ford'
      address: {street: '1 the street', city: 'Gotham'},
      friends: [ {name: 'Tony'}, {name: 'Sandra' }]
    }
```

I want to compare the second object against the first and remove any items in the second not found in the first. I have this:

```
filterData: function (obj, filterObj) { 

    var newObj = {};    

    for (var key in filterObj) {

      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

        if (typeof obj[key] == 'object' && typeof filterObj[key] == 'object' || typeof filterObj[key] == 'array') {
          newObj[key] = this.filterData(obj[key], filterObj[key]);

        }else {
          newObj[key] = obj[key];
        }
      }
    }

    return newObj;      

}
```

Which nearly works, but only keeps the first item in the array and then switches the array to an object.

So my expected output is:

```
 var result =   { name: 'Bob',
          age: '23',            
          address: {street: '1 the street', city: 'Gotham'},
          friends: [ {name: 'Tony'}, {name: 'Sandra' }]
        }
```

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ddqLqz9d/

Comment: `var arr = []; typeof arr` returns `"object"` ; try using `Array.isArray(arr)`

Comment: I know you're only using jQuery but you might be interested by lodash's defaultsDeep() function : https://lodash.com/docs#defaultsDeep Not sure it will work with the inner array though

Comment: Your code could be much simpler if it work with object reference, not copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof []` returns `"object"`. Try using `Array.isArray()` to check for value of property being an array; changing `if` condition to

```
if (typeof obj[key] == 'object' && typeof filterObj[key] == 'object'
          /* check if `obj[key]` and `filterObj[key]` are arrays */
          && ![obj[key], filterObj[key]].every(Array.isArray))
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ddqLqz9d/1/